# How can attacker know the router vendor without physical/visual access to it?

Tags: attacks, wireless, router

How can attacker know the (victim's) router vendor, for testing default passwords, without physical/visual access to it?

Comment: By connecting to it. The router announces itself.

Comment: Paradox detected: "without physical/visual access to it". 
Please edit your question.

Comment: @mootmoot what's the paradox? one can have visual access without physical access

Comment: @schroeder  We will have philosophy question such as "physical connection".

Comment: @mootmoot I think it is generally understood that sending packets is a logical connection, not a physical one

Comment: @schroeder I dont understand what you mean by connecting to it, if I dont have password I cant connect

Comment: @Leonardo you need to connect in order to supply a password ....

Comment: @schoeder yea i got it later on what you meant, nm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by scanning with NMAP tool you can know the vendor and other information of that device. Here, I am scanning a Singaporean router with IP 93.186.133.137 and the results are following,

```
[arif@arif:~]$ sudo nmap -O 93.186.133.137
Starting Nmap 7.50 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-07-06 14:17 +06
Nmap scan report for ae6.singapore2.sin.seabone.net (93.186.133.137)
Host is up (0.058s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
20/tcp   filtered ftp-data
21/tcp   filtered ftp
22/tcp   filtered ssh
23/tcp   filtered telnet
111/tcp  open     rpcbind
179/tcp  filtered bgp
514/tcp  filtered shell
646/tcp  open     ldp
3221/tcp filtered xnm-clear-text
Device type: router
Running: Juniper JUNOS 9.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:juniper:junos:9.2r1.10
OS details: Juniper JUNOS 9.2R1.10
Network Distance: 4 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ 
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 9.49 seconds
```

If you look at this output closely you can see that in the **Device** heading it says exactly **router** and in **OS details** heading it says not only about it's vendor name (**Juniper**) but with it's version (**JUNOS 9.2R1.10**). So most of the time it's pretty easy to guess about OS. I am saying guess because some specific security feature can mislead us about OS.

Comment: what about simply connecting to it?

Comment: Yeah, I was missing that part. Sorry